# Get data from external HFSPlush drive

Tags: filesystem

I have an external USB drive that is HFSPlus filesystem. When connected to my Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) it is read only. I can't even copy files from this drive to the machine's hard drive. How do I get data off the drive?

Edit:
The pertinent part of `lsblk` shows the usb drive:

sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0  31.5K  0 part
├─sdb2   8:18   0   128M  0 part
├─sdb3   8:19   0   1.8T  0 part /media/myusername/WD-SSD-2TB

Answer (score 3):

There are some utilities that you'll need installed before you can effectively read from (and sometimes write to) an HFS+ partition.

Try this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Install the `hfsprogs` package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
   ```
2. Mount the external drive:

   ```
   sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdb1 /media/mntpoint
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Be sure to replace `/dev/sdb1` with the proper partition that you would like to read, and `/media/mntpoint` with the actual location you want to access the files from.</sub>

   If the drive is already mounted, you will need to re-mount it:

   ```
   sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /dev/sdb1 /media/mntpoint
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Same notes as above</sub>
3. Access your files

One important thing to pay attention to is whether the HFS+ drive is journaled or not. If it is journaled, then you will likely not be able to write files to the disk. If it is not journaled, then you may have two-way access with the device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not clear on the /media/mntpoint. I created a directory `/home/myusername/HFSPlusDrive/` but this is apparently not the thing to do, as I get a 'mount point not mounted or bad option' error. What do I do here?